# Complex Fourier series coefficients of a periodic function

Tags: fourier-series, change-of-variable

[image: The problem I must solve]

I have tried integrating to find a relationship between $C_n^{(m)}$ and $C_n^{(m-1)}$, but I don't know if I'm right, as the integral is very confusing.

Also, even if I am wrong on the relationship, I attempted section b) and I did not know how to approach the change of variable.

Any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but if you wanted to find $C_n^{(m-1)}$ wouldn't you differentiate the function in question?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$\frac{d^2x^{2m}}{dx^2}=(2m)(2m-1)x^{2m-2}=(2m)(2m-1)x^{2(m-1)}.$$

Now use (or rederive, using integration by parts) the fact that

$$\hat{f''}(n)=in\hat{f'}(n)=-n^2\hat{f}(n).$$

Take the Fourier-series transform of the first equation, specifically the left and right sides, to get:

$$-n^2c^{(m)}_n=(2m)(2m-1)c^{(m-1)}_n.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am still confused though. Why are you using x^(2m-1)? I understand how you got the second derivative, but I'm not really sure why yo did that. I also undersand the identity you mentioned in the second equation, and I can see where you're going, but I don't know how you got the last equation. Could you please provide some more detail? Thank you very much

Comment: @Lewis Thomas: ah I made an index mistake. Fixed

Comment: For the last equation, Take the transform of $\frac{d^2x^{2m}}{dx^2}$ to get th left side, and then take the transform of $x^{2(m-1)}$ to get the right side.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the trouble, but I still find some issues with this. How are you chosing "n" as the variable for the fourier transform? Shouldn't it be k, meaning that the transform of f''(x) should be -k^2*F(x)?

Comment: Here's my notation, the $n$ refers to the index, which I've emphasized by adding brackets:

$$[\hat{f_m}](n):=c^{(m)}_n:=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_m(x)e^{-inx}dx$$

are we on the same page now?

Comment: Umm, I'd love to, but I don't understand how you can define Cn(m) to be the fourier transform of fm(x). By the way, how do you format your respones to make them display a 
mathematical expression?

Comment: @LewisThomas: How would you define $c^{(m)}_n$ then? For formatting: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I'm not sure, I just found that confusing, but I guess that works. Can you please take a look at the last part of the problem, where a change of variables is required? Thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry for the persistence, but I really don't know how to approach the change of variables that is being asked for in the last section of the problem above. Do you know how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117407/discussion-between-lewis-thomas-and-alex-r).